# Quick issue with Python 3.1 http server

Tags: python, ip, port

I'm have an issue with running the built in Python server that comes with 3.1, this may or may not be an issue with Python, in fact it probably isn't.
I start my server in the correct directory with "python -m http.server 8000" as the documentation suggests (http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/http.server.html).
When I navigate to that port on my local network with another computer using the url 192.168.2.104:8000 (my local ip and the port) my page loads. When I use my global IP, however, it stops working. Port 8000 is forwarded correctly. I used www.yougetsignal.com to verify that port 8000 was open using my global IP. Why in the world would Chrome be saying "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to [REDACTED]:8000" then? Other server applications (such as my Minecraft server) work just fine. Is there something I'm missing? Furthermore, why would yougetsignal connect to my port but not Chrome?

Comment: Are you testing the port forwarding from within your LAN or from a host outside your LAN?

Comment: I would assume that yougetsignal uses its own server to test, would this be a bad assumption?

Comment: That's a good assumption; how about _you_? When you use Chrome to test the port forwarding, are you testing from inside your LAN or from outside your LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most routers ports are only mapped when someone connects from the outside (internet/WAN). You're testing it from your LAN so basically you're connecting to your router when you use your public IP. Ask a friend to test, i.e. from an outside connection.